# How might one redesign a "Curiosity-class" rover for a mission to Vesta or Ceres?

Tags: rovers, mission-design, ceres

Vishnu Reddy ([1](https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/reddy/person/vishnu-reddy), [2](https://tucson.com/news/local/vishnu-reddy-went-from-new-delhi-journalist-to-ua-asteroid-hunter/article_0a0a0363-1978-5f2b-bf13-a37e168b0098.html), [3](https://www.thebetterindia.com/229673/indian-scientist-vishnu-reddy-asteroid-hunter-university-arizona-nasa-inspiring-journey-ros174/)) and their research group are quite active in space exploration both in Earth-based observation and now in the design of future spacecraft, and have recently pseudo-confirmed that the object currently designated as [2020 SO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_SO) is likely covered in stainless steel and so is probably the rocket body who's trajectory it so nicely matches. ([4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48854/12102), [5](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46749/12102))

In the NASA "people" page [Vishnu Reddy; Scientist, University of Arizona Lunar and Planetary Laboratory](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/people/280/vishnu-reddy/)
 is the following exchange:

> **Q:** Do you have a yet-to-be-achieved life goal?
>
> **A:** I would love to have a rover on Vesta like how we have on Mars. Maybe it can be done in our lifetime.

**Question:** What are the engineering challenges to putting a rover on [4 Vesta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta) or [1 Ceres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet))? Starting from a "Curiosity-class" rover, how might one redesign it for such a mission?

**note:** A "Curiosity-class" rover means a unit of comparable size and sophistication that is able to move itself a considerable distance over time, avoid getting trapped by obstacles in some way and collect a comparably diverse set of data and have a comparable amount of command and data traffic with Earth. *It doesn't have to necessarily look like Curiosity!*

"bonus points" for exploring why Reddy might have mentioned Vesta but not Ceres.

Comment: No wheels needed in such low gravity.

Comment: @A.Rumlin [like this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21709/12102)? :-)  also see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17668/12102) to *Does new technology make it advantageous to have walking rovers?*

Comment: like Phobos-2 lander  at 6:56 https://youtu.be/m2dz7s8-yYg?t=416

Comment: @A.Rumlin yes that is likely to work much better. I've added a note to the question.